# How to group by date and not datetime in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle18c

I have few columns which are time and method etc. I need to display the operations performed on a day.

```
time,method 
01-Sep-2022,1
01-Sep-2022,2
01-Sep-2022,2
01-Sep-2022,3
01-Sep-2022,3
01-Sep-2022,3
02-Sep-2022,1
03-Sep-2022,1
04-Sep-2022,1


Output
time,method 
01-Sep-2022,1,1
01-Sep-2022,2,2
01-Sep-2022,3,3
02-Sep-2022,1,1
03-Sep-2022,1,1
04-Sep-2022,1,1
```

How to write the Oracle query ?

Comment: will u explain how does 02-Sep-2022 is ,2,1 |03-Sep-2022 is 2,1 | 04-Sep-2022 is 2,1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to group by date and not datetime in Oracle?

Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data-type; it only has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` and both always contain a time component (even if the user interface you are using may choose to only display the date component, it still always has a time component).

To group by the date component, use the `TRUNC` function to truncate the time component back to midnight so that all values on the same day have the same truncated time:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(time) AS day,
       method,
       count(*)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY TRUNC(time), method
ORDER BY day, method;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (time, method) AS
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + INTERVAL '2' HOUR, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + INTERVAL '4' HOUR, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + INTERVAL '5' HOUR, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-01' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-02' + INTERVAL '7' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-03' + INTERVAL '8' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-09-04' + INTERVAL '9' HOUR, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DAY | METHOD | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022-09-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-09-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-09-04 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L2KApyCS)

Comment: this works,one doubt,so when i try to filter the date range with where clause,I am not able to do so.I wrote: time >= TO_DATE(:startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') and time < TO_DATE(:enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY').When I try to use bind variable,it fails .But with substituion variables,it runs fine

Comment: @coredev If you are using bind variables and they are already dates then do **NOT** use `TO_DATE` on them.

Comment: I am using '09/01/2022' as values for example.

Comment: @coredev If the bind variables have the `DATE` data type then you are forcing an implicit string-to-date conversion when you set them as bind variables and then a second implicit conversion from date-to-string in your code as `TO_DATE` takes  a string as the first argument before performing an explicit third conversion from string-to date (which is why I said **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a `DATE`). If you are passing the bind variables as string (and not dates) then it should work; if it doesn't then you need to provide a [MRE].

Answer (score 0):

you should use group by time,method.

```
CREATE TABLE timdt 
(
    time    date,
    method  int
);

INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('01-Sep-2022', '1');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('01-Sep-2022', '2');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('01-Sep-2022', '2');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('01-Sep-2022', '3');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('01-Sep-2022', '3');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('01-Sep-2022', '3');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('02-Sep-2022', '1');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('03-Sep-2022', '2');
INSERT INTO timdt (time,method)VALUES('04-Sep-2022', '3');

select time,method,count(*) from timdt group by time,method order by time,method;
```

OUTPUT:

```
TIME    METHOD  COUNT(*)
01-SEP-22   1   1
01-SEP-22   2   2
01-SEP-22   3   3
02-SEP-22   1   1
03-SEP-22   2   1
04-SEP-22   3   1
```